# Google Sheets multiple conditions with nested If statements?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula

I'm really struggling with this formula, but I think I'm overthinking it. I'm not sure what's the proper way to write this:

**What I want to happen is:**
If cell A1 = John AND 
cell B1 = Buyer
then take the dollar amount in C1 and multiply it by 10% 
ELSE 
If cell A1 = John AND 
cell B1 = Seller
then take the amount in C1 and multiple it by 25% BUT
If A1 is NOT equal to John, then return a currency value of $0

I sincerely appreciate any help.  Thank you!
Lisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=if(A1="John",ifs(B1="Buyer",C1*10%,B1="Seller",C1*25%),0)
```

Comment: Yes!  Kishan, thank you SO very much!! VERY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=IF(A1="John", 
 IF(B1="Buyer",  C1*10%, 
 IF(B1="Seller", C1*25%, )), 0)
```

or:

```
=IF((A1="John")*(B1="Buyer"),  C1*10%,
 IF((A1="John")*(B1="Seller"), C1*25%, 0))
```